# WinPcap, проблема с получение шлюза от TAP адаптера OpenVPN

Tags: c#, c++, c, сеть, tcp-ip

Для отправки `TCP` запроса нужно сначала получить `MAC` адрес шлюза (средствами `ARP` запроса). С физическими сетевыми адаптерами - все отлично и понятно. Проблема возникает при использовании `OpenVPN`, где в роли **виртуального** сетевого адаптера выступает `TAP` адаптер. У него нет шлюза (шлюз просто не указан в настройках).

Есть ли способ обойти это?